# How can i make my Discord Bot (Javascript) reply to the user in tag, when a certain question is asked?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want my Discord Bot tagging to the user when a certain question is asked,
in example the user says "Hello" and the Bot reply with *Hello @User*

Answer (score 3):

```
if(message.content == "hello") {
 message.reply("hello!") }
```

or something along those lines!
you could also do:

```
if(message.content == "hello") {
message.channel.send(`Hello ${message.author}!`) }
```

I'm new to Stack overflow so sorry if this is hard to understand.

Comment: Thanks, that's what i have looking for!